# Nginx: How to access files outside of root using PHP?

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

Originally I had a bunch of folders in my root /var/www/html folder protected with `location` blocks like this:

```
location ~ /(folder1|folder2|folder3) {
  internal;
}
```

But now I realize it would make more sense if I just took them out of my root folder entirely. I want to be able to send those files through a PHP file though, where I am doing something like this:

```
$file_path = '/' . $path . '/' . $prefix . '.' . $suffix;
header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $file_path);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

But if I take those folders outside of my /var/www/html and put them in say /var/www/protected, how can I access those files in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `root ...` inside location tag to differentiate it...
you can use `auth_request` for more option here [auth_request nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html)